# Display cells that contain X in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

No idea how to title this one.

[image]

Suppose I have the above table. I want the column "used in" to display the name of every food that uses the food on this row, to look like this:

[image]

The separator is unimportant, I just used a ; as I like how it looks. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B3</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",,FILTER(A$3:A$6,1-ISERR(SEARCH(A3,C$3:C$6)),"-"))
```

---

Or Using one single dynamic array formula called `BYROW()` passing a custom `LAMBDA()` calculations. Do note one vital point, that `TEXTJOIN()` function has character limitations hence using the fill down approach is more appropriate in this scenario, however, if its within the limit you could try this as well:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _food, A3:A6,
     BYROW(A3:A6,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(";",,
     FILTER(_food,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(x,C3:C6)),"-")))))
```

---